# Why is vectorization so much more effective with floats than with doubles?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, openmp

I noticed that when vectorizing a loop in a C program, the speedup achieved is much greater when using operands of the type float compared to double operands.

Example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    a[i] += b[i] * c[i];
}
```

When a, b and c arrays of size 20,000 each and I repeat this loop 1,000,000:

- Without vectorization it takes around 24 seconds with both floats and doubles
- With auto vectorization (compiling with -O1 -ftree-vectorize) it takes 7 seconds with floats and 21 seconds with doubles
- With OpenMP (#pramga omp simd) it is similar to the above bullet point.

  What could be the reason for this?

Edit:
Further information:

1. Processor: Intel Core i7-2677M CPU @ 1.80GHz
2. The surrounding code is nothing but array allocations (using calloc) and a loop where the arrays b and c are filled with constant values.

Comment: What processor? What SIMD features does it have? What are its performance characteristics? Most likely, its `float` SIMD instructions operate on twice as many elements per instruction as its `double` SIMD instructions. How fast is the memory? What is the surrounding code—is it known to the compiler whether `a`, `b`, and `c` may overlap?

Comment: Thanks. I've added some further information, I'm not sure how to find the answer to all of the questions, I'm afraid.

Comment: Keep in mind that often in modern CPUs the main bottleneck is often RAM bandwidth; i.e. it doesn't much matter how fast your CPU can multiply two values if it is spending 90% of its time waiting for those values to be fetched from RAM anyway.   And an array of doubles is twice as large as the equivalent array of floats, and therefore likely to require more fetching of data from RAM (vs having the needed data already present in the CPU's local cache)

Comment: Three `float` arrays of 20000 elements take 234 KiB in total, which fits in the L2 data cache of a single core. Three `double` arrays take 469 KiB, which doesn't fit in the L2 data cache. Also, with `float` you have 8 elements in a vector register, while using `double` halves it, therefore you get only half the FLOPS.

Answer (score 1):

With many of these operations SIMD (single-instruction, multiple data) instructions come into play. Floats are half the size of doubles and so twice as many of them can be dealt with in a single instruction. I am,however, surprised that the speed is triple using floats rather than simply doubled. I suspect, but don't know for sure, that is due to floats being much easier to operate on - the actual mantissa extractions etc.

Comment: I think I get what you're saying - but shouldn't that also affect the computation time significantly without the application of vectorization?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `-ffast-math` option?  This may have other side affects that you'll have to look into (e.g.  a potential loss of precision).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried it while using doubles, and the computation time did not change in this case.

Comment: Check out this article from Intel [here](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/floating-point-performance-and-vectorization.html).  It looks like it is applicable, particular the section that says "Not all of the operators are supported for 32 bits, meaning that some source code will not be able to be vectorized unless smaller operands are used."